# Why am i getting 'install peer dependencies' error when installing inertia.js within a vue.js project?

Tags: vue.js, inertiajs

I want to use inertia.js within a vue.js app, but getting an error when following the default setup instructions:

```
npm install @inertiajs/inertia @inertiajs/inertia-vue3
```

error:

```
@inertiajs/inertia-vue3@0.5.2 requires a peer of vue@^3.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

i've tried previous versions and installing vue separately, but still getting same error. what am i missing? thanks

Comment: think i've fixed the warning by manually installing peer dependencies for vue3 using this code: npm install --save-dev "vue@^3.0.0"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for anyone that encountered the same warning message, run this command to install peer dependencies and fix the warning: `npm install --save-dev "vue@^3.0.0"`